# XSLT Copy node doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transform, saxon

I'd like to copy some nodes exactly as they are using the folowing template:

```
<xsl:template match="example1 | ext-link | example2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

So for the following input:

```
<ext-link ext-link-type="uri" xlink:href="http://www.gnuplot.info/">http://www.gnuplot.info/</ext-link>
```

I would get exatly te same:

```
<ext-link ext-link-type="uri" xlink:href="http://www.gnuplot.info/">http://www.gnuplot.info/</ext-link>
```

However the result is like this:

```
<ext-link>urihttp://www.gnuplot.info/http://www.gnuplot.info/</ext-link>
```

I'm using Java, Saxon.

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look for  **XSLT identity transform** (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT)
Add a `@*` to your template match.
Try:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | example1 | ext-link | example2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Will this only copy the attributes of subsequent elements in the match expression?

Comment: This depends on the rest of your stylesheet. To avoid any other node output you may add `<xsl:template match="*" />`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've posted an alternative solution let me knwo whta you think. I'm a bit consorned about mathching all attributes, though for this particular problem it seems to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternative solution,  I would like to know what do you think. It suits my purposes well.

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:copy>
```

Comment: That's the version I use if I don't want to make any changes to attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to copy the elements and their content exactly as they are , one more option would be to just use

```
<xsl:template match="example1 | ext-link | example2">
   <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Though hr_117's push-style answer using apply-templates is generally the preferred one as it is more easily extensible.